# Attaching many to many relations while still binding to created event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

So I've run into this issue a few times and now I've decided that I want to find a better solution.

For examples sake, I have two models, `Order` & `Product`. There is a many to many relation so that an order can have multiple products and a product can of course have multiple orders. Table structure looks like the below -

orders

- id
- more fields...

products

- id
- more fields...

product_orders

- order_id
- product_id

So when an order is created I run the following -

```
$order = Order::create($request->validated())
$order->products()->attach([1,2,3,4...]);
```

So this creates an order and attaches the relevant products to it.

However, I want to use an observer, to determine when the order is created and send out and perform related tasks off the back (send an order confirmation email, etc.) The problem being, at the time the order created observer is triggered, the products aren't yet attached.

Is there any way to do the above, establishing all the many to many relationships and creating the order at the same time so I can access linked products within the Order created observer?

**Use case 1**

AJAX call hits PUT /api/order which in turn calls `Order::place()` method. Once an order is created, an email is sent to the customer who placed the order. Now I could just put an event dispatch within this method that in turn triggers the email send but this just feels a bit hacky.

```
public static function place (SubmitOrderRequest $request)
{
    $order = Order::create($request->validated());

    $order->products()->attach($request->input('products'));

    return $order;
}
```

**Use case 2**

I'm feature testing to make sure that an email is sent when an order is created. Now, this test passes (and email sends work), but it's unable to output the linked products at this point in execution.

```
/**
 * @test
 **/
public function an_email_is_sent_on_order_creation()
{
    Mail::fake();

    factory(Order::class)->create();

    Mail::assertSent(OrderCreatedMailable::class);
}


Thanks,
Chris.
```

Comment: If you are using observers to listen to events, and the current list of events are not what you are looking for. Can you not just thrown a new event after creating an order and adding all the products? Like in here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events

Comment: @RobBiermann - sure I can but for testing purposes etc I would like to expect a standard event. Say for example in testing I create an order using database seeding, but in production I have a method on an order called `place`, I'd need to fire that event in both places

Comment: Can you post both your usecases in your issue description? It helps with figuring out a solution :) I think it could come down to triggering event in a function, and then using that function in both seeder and model(place) function. But for now that is just speculation :)

Comment: @RobBiermann I've added a couple of use cases. As mentioned, I could just fire an event within `Order::place()` but it just feels wrong - maybe I'm being too code anal?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem could be transaction events as provided by [this package from fntneves](https://github.com/fntneves/laravel-transactional-events).

Personally, I stumbled upon the idea of transactional events for another reason. I had the issue that my business logic required the execution of some queued jobs after a specific entity had been created. Because my entities got created in batches within a transaction, it was possible that an event was fired (and the corresponding event listener was queued), although the transaction was rolled back because of an error shortly after. The result were queued listeners that always failed.

Your scenario seems comparable to me as you don't want to execute your event listeners immediately due to missing data which is only attached after the model was actually created. For this reason, I suggest wrapping your order creation and all other tasks that manipulate the order within a transaction. Combined with the usage of said package, you can then fire the *model created* event as the actual event listener will only be called **after** the transaction has been committed. The code for all this basically comes down to what you already described:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    $order = Order::create($request->validated());
    $order->products()->attach($request->input('products'));
});
```

In your model, you'd simply define an `OrderCreated` event or use an observer as suggested in the other answer:

```
class Order
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'created' => OrderCreated::class,
    ];
}

class OrderCreated implements TransactionalEvent
{
     public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  \App\Order  $order
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for! So by using this package, and wrapping the order creation & product attaching within a transaction, I can ensure that my `OrderCreated` event only runs after the transaction has completed. I've just tested it and its working great. Perfect and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine `boot` method in your model, if product ids is static

```
class Order extends Eloquent {

   protected static function boot() {
      parent::boot();

      static::saving(function ($user) {
        $this->products()->attach([1,2,3,4...]);
      });
    }
}
```

Or use [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers)

```
class OrderObserver 
{
    public function created($model)
    {
          //
    }
}
```

And register this

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        Order::observe(new OrderObserver());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in reality product ID's are dynamic. Thank you for your input though

Comment: You can user request() in your observer for example